# Does Stack Exchange ever celebrate its own anniversary?

Tags: feature-request

Stack Exchange is a great internet resource that's been around since (what?) 2009.  Does it ever celebrate its own anniversary?

---

As far as I can tell the answer seems to be 'no'.
Wouldn't it be nice to celebrate Stack Exchange milestones (such as 5th Anniversary)?

Comment: We're a little late for the 5th Anniversary ...

Comment: surely we can plan ahead for 10 years, no? ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/

Comment: @Glorindel - true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not itself but it does celebrate certain milestones for Stack Overflow, Super User, rep counts, and itself:

**Stack Overflow:**

- [Jon Skeet reaches 100,000 rep](http://stackoverflow.blog/2009/09/congrats-on-100k-rep/)
- [1st Year Anniversary](http://stackoverflow.blog/2009/08/one-year-of-stack-overflow/)
- [100,000th Question](http://stackoverflow.blog/2009/02/happy-100000th-question/)
- [5 Year Anniversary of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/)
- [10 Million Questions (Actual Post Removed)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302925/10-million-questions-or-10-million-good-questions)

**Super User:**

- [1st Year Anniversary Super Contest](http://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/)
- [First User with 10k Rep](http://stackoverflow.blog/2009/09/the-first-super-user-with-10k-rep/)

**Other (Blog or Community):**

- [1,000,000th User](http://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/1000000th-user/)
- [4th Year Anniversary for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163289/happy-4th-anniversary-stack-overflow)
- [2nd Year Anniversary for Super User](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3139/ideas-for-celebrating-super-users-2nd-anniversary)

That's all I could find here, the [Stack Exchange blog](http://stackoverflow.blog/company/community/page63/) (have fun with the 63 pages of articles), Meta Stack Overflow, and Meta Super User.

Comment: Coming soon: Jon Skeet reaches 1,000,000 rep :D

Comment: @TravisJ: 'soon' being in about 1 year..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Close enough